# NDK Expected unqualified-id before '^' token

Tags: c++, android-ndk, block

I'm new to NDK and new to JAVA, so please bear with me.
I have c++ files that I want to build it through NDK build.gradle. And I have the below in my build.gradle file:

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.blabla.blabla"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            moduleName "test"
            cFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions"
            stl "gnustl_shared"
        }
    }
```

and I have this line in local.properties:

```
ndk.dir= pathToMyNDK/AndroidStudio/ndk
```

In one my C++ files, I have a block definition like this:

```
typedef void (^ABCD)(string, string);
```

and a function that takes an argument of that type:

```
void generateAlphabetLetters(ABCD alph){}
```

When I try to build the files with NDK, I get the following error that I cannot solve:
***Expected unqualified-id before '^' token***

Comment: Where did you get this source file? As the error says, the `^` character is not valid in that position. I think I've seen it used in "C++/CLI", where it has to do with managed code, but not in proper standard C++.

Comment: @zenzelezz I wrote the code, I need to use blocks in my application

Comment: From a quick google search it seems like that is specifically an Apple extension, again not part of standard C++. Could you elaborate on what it is you need it for?

Comment: @zenzelezz it is not mandatory to use block but that will make my code neat. And I have blocks in multiple C++ files

Comment: You say you have blocks in other C++ files, are those also in Android NDK projects?

Comment: @zenzelezz thanks for the help, I thought blocks are used in c++, turned out I have to use lambdas instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a syntax error as the compiler tells you.

```
typedef void (^ABCD)(string, string);
```

is not valid c++.

You have lambdas in standard c++.

Answer (score 0):

Blocks are Apple's C extension. If you want use them in Android, you should either rewrite your code to use C++11 lambdas (supported by NDK's gcc and clang) or use [CrystaX NDK](https://www.crystax.net/android/ndk), where Objective-C and Objective-C++ supported (including Objective-C blocks).